# Display checkbox in gridview using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

Using below code we are able to successfully display records.

Requirement - We want to another column (Status) and display checkbox. It can be enabled/disabled based on value fetched from database.

```
<asp:GridView ID="HorizontalGrid" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"  GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="Horizontal_OnRowDataBound">
                                                <Columns>             
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" HtmlEncode="false"  />
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" HtmlEncode="false" />
                                                </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
```

This is code behind:

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = TestDatabase; Integrated Security = TRUE");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Category");
    dt.Columns.Add("Description");

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = dr[0];
        row[1] = (string)dr[1];
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    HorizontalGrid.DataSource = dt;
    HorizontalGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Just add a TemplateField and place a CheckBox in it.